# Is there a term to refer to a weighted mean that's weighted by a function of percentile (using a kernel)?

Tags: terminology, kernel-smoothing, weighted-mean, central-tendency

I came-up with a type of central tendency which is a weighted mean. The weighting is based on percentile, with values closer to the median having a higher weight. It's similar to the idea of a truncated mean, but it's a soft approach to dealing with outliers.
For example, if *x* is the percentile of each value in the set, the weights can be determined with these 3 functions

```
x(x-1)
(x(x-1))²
(x(x-1))³
```

[image: Red=x(x-1)(4) Blue=(x(x-1))² Green=(x(x-1))³]

I'm sure I'm not the first to come-up with this. Is there an existing term for this kind of central tendency?

Comment: Presumably you are using $x(1-x)$ or its powers

Comment: A normalized form for those weights is $x^n(1-x)^n(2n+1)!/(n!)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Weightings based on percentiles also occur in rank-dependent expected utility ([RDEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-dependent_expected_utility)), so you could call these rank-dependent weightings or rank-dependent expectations.